# Dynamic script with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

EDIT: I have the first part ready now, but I don't know how to make the last part where it says:
Number 1 is 5
Number 2 is 5
Number 3 is 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int amount;
    int *p_array;
    int i;
    int j;
    p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);

    if(p_array == NULL) {
        printf("malloc of size %d failed\n", 50);
    }

    printf("How much numbers would you like to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    for(int i = 1; i <= amount; ++i) {
        printf("number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &p_array[1]);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j <= amount; ++j) {
        printf("%d", p_array[i]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need an array for this and not pointers. BTW: `printf(&a);` is totally wrong. OT: you can reuse the variable `a` for the second for loop, no need for the `b` variable.

Comment: *"So if there's code wrong, please tell me."* - Does it work?

Comment: But is it possible to do with pointers?

Comment: Yes it's possible to do it with pointers, just like it is possible to scrubb the floor with a toothbrush. Arrays are the proper way to do this.

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf` to see if you have read a numer at all.

Comment: BTW: there are no "scripts" in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a cople of problems in the code, I think the main issue is that when ever you want to scan an unknown amount of data, you have to dynamicly allocate memory. because you cant tell the computer exectly how much memory your program needs (while writing the code), you need to allocate memory during run-time of your program.
to allocate the memory you can use malloc, which will allocate memory on the heap during run-time, [for mor information about malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

(importent: when ever you use malloc you have to free the allocated data in order to avoid memory leacks).

a better way to implement this problem would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {

int numbers;

//get the amount of numbers
printf("How much numbers would you like to enter?\n");
scanf("%i", &numbers);

//allocate memory(on the heap) for the numbers
int* input = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*numbers);

//get the numbers
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; ++i) {
    printf("Number %d\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}
//print the numbers
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; ++i) {
    printf("Number %d is: %d\n", i + 1, input[i]);
}
//free the memory to avoid memory leaks.
free(input);
}
```

hope it helps, if you have more quastions I would be happy to help,
good luck!  =)

Comment: **this implementation assumes the input is correct (i didn't check the input)

Comment: Thank you so much man, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an array that can hold the numbers:

```
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    int a[numbers];
```

Next, you can access the array with a pointer:

```
   int *pa= a;
   for (i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        scanf("%d", pa);
        pa++;
   }
```